# Facebook and Crawl-delay in robots.txt?

Tags: seo, facebook, robots.txt, web-crawlers

Do Facebook's webcrawling bots (for example [facebookexternalhit/*](http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php))  respect the [`Crawl-delay:`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard#Crawl-delay_directive) directive in *robots.txt* files?

Comment: [Don't dupe questions across sites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716531/facebook-and-crawl-delay-in-robots-txt). You got your answer over there, by the way. (See Jeff's bio.)

Comment: Boo... thanks @Su' - now how do I withdraw my bounty???

Answer (score 2):

This same question was [asked on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716531/facebook-and-crawl-delay-in-robots-txt).

The answer is that the Facebook scraper does **not** obey *robots.txt* or support a crawl delay.  The best that you can hope for is implementing some sort of server side throttling.  Some code for doing that has been provided as one of the answers on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -1):

Facebook does not have a bot that spiders the internet. They only track events on your site when tied with their Graph API.

Comment: Not a bot, a scraper. What evidence do you have for your claim? There's data disputing your claim here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9165191/63094

Comment: Evidence, is 100s of log files.  If you dont use facebook on your site, facebook will bot bot or spider it.  The answer of Stack overflow is exactly the same.  Facebook connects to your site when it is shared or if you use facebook FBML or other facebook code.